# Google Tag Manager: get value as variable after specific text

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to capture the value of the "sku" as a variable in GTM. This value will change on every product page.

The code on page looks like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "sku": "305FS-UJNA5",
  "offers": [{
        "@type": "Offer",
        "price": "99.00",
        "availability": "InStock",
        "priceCurrency": "USD"
        }]
}
</script>
```

The variable expected to be captured: 305FS-UJNA5 (without double quotes).

Is there a way to accomplish this by using a custom javascript variable type that will search for `"sku": "` on the page and return the value till the next double quote?

Or, what what would be the best way to accomplish this?

I've tried the search but returns undefined in GTM...

```
function () {
var content = document.body.innerText;
var query=""sku": "";
if (content.search(query) > -1 ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not leverage GTM and push data that you need into the dataLayer? (Not saying your approach is wrong, but ... just throwing it out there, since you have GTM already.)

Comment: @nyuen If it's in dataLayer that would be fantastic. But how do you get GTM to read that value of 305FS-UJNA5 and push it to dataLayer?

Comment: You need to do a `dataLayer.push` of key/value pairs. I can't show you much more without putting it into an answer that might not help. But you can Google datalayer push. You would do it with an `event` so that GTM can easily pick up the data and use them in your tags.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I don't think it's relevant (yet). I think one of the issues is that your structured data is not readily accessible. If it had an ID, for example, then you could follow this: http://www.autoidlabs.org.uk/GS1Digital/Demos/GS1vocab/gs1JSON-LD-with-JavaScript.html. I'm not sure how you would be able to otherwise access that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to accept a hackish solution

```
      <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
                <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Product",
          "sku": "305FS-UJNA5",
          "offers": [{
                "@type": "Offer",
                "price": "99.00",
                "availability": "InStock",
                "priceCurrency": "USD"
                }]
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>    
            json = {};
                scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
                for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
                  script = scripts[i];
                  if(script.getAttribute('type') != "application/ld+json") {
                      continue;
                  }
                  json = JSON.parse(script.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                  datalayer.push({ // dl must be initialized before
                    'event':'skuCapture',
                     'sku': json.sku
                  });
                }


            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

This loads the contents of the script-Tag into a variable called "json" and you can load that into a global js variable or push individual properties to the datalayer (i.e. in the example json.sku will hold the sku). If you do not do this on an existing event (e.g . Dom Ready) you will need to push a custom event to make GTM aware of the value.

Obviously you can put the script in a custom HTML tag (as long it is run after your script tag has rendered) if you cannot change the page code. This is just meant to be a working example.

This worked for me in Chrome, it is not tested with other browsers or tested for side effects so you'll probably need to expand on the idea, but it is doable (even if it looks ugly).

Actually this can be written slightly more concise:

```
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("[type='application/ld+json']");
    for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
      script = scripts[i];
      json = JSON.parse(script.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      console.log(json.sku);
    }
```

which selects only the script tags with the proper type attribute. And if you know for certain you have only one script tag you could use `document.querySelector` instead of `document.querySelectorAll` and dispense with the loop (since that would return a single result).

Comment: Good answer! I thought there might just be another way, but I guess not.

Comment: @nyuen, I really hope there is another way, because that surely is not a beautiful solution - but it's the only one I was able to find.

Comment: Probably just as well, as OP doesn't want to involve devs.